# Is linear manifold a pure algebraic concept?

Tags: vector-spaces, manifolds

I was wondering if linear manifold is a pure algebraic concept? Here is its definition from planetmath:

> Suppose $V$ is a vector space and suppose that $L$ is a non-empty
>   subset of $V$. If there exists a $v \in V$ such that $L+v=\{v+l, l \in
>  L\}$ is a vector subspace of $V$ , then $L$ is a linear manifold of
>   $V$.

If yes, why is there a "manifold" (which is a topological space) in its name?

Or is it a topological vector space with some topology unspecified but assumed

Thanks!

Comment: Every finite-dimensional vector space$ V$ can be made into a manifold in a standard way, by choosing a vector space isomorphism between V and $\mathbb R^n$; the change-of- coordinate maps are linear and invertible. The condition on your $L$ is just so that it becomes a subspace by going thru the origin.

Comment: Linear manifold is a term used e.g. by Halmos and J.B. Conway to mean what is usually called linear subspace. In turn, they require a linear subspace to be closed (this is only of interest if you're working with infinite-dimensional topological vector spaces). I guess the reason is simply brevity: you need both concepts in functional analysis and always saying "closed subspace" or "not neccesarily closed subspace" is going to be mildly tedious. I don't think linear manifold is used that widely nowadays.

Comment: @Georges: I checked in Cristescu's book which planetmath cites as a source and in that book indeed an affine subspace is meant. Both Schaefer and Kelley-Namioka also use this terminology: from p.5 of Kelley-Namioka in the Springer GTM edition: "A set of the form $x + F$, where $F$ is a linear subspace, is called a **linear manifold** or **linear variety**, or a **flat**." I don't like to call affine things linear, but that may be my personal spleen. I  don't know where the linear manifold terminology comes from. Banach himself had the good taste not to use it in his book.

Comment: Dear @Theo, thank you for these explanations. Like you, I don't like it when affine things are called linear. I had erased my comments before seeing your present answer because I didn't want to give the impression that I wanted a flame war against planetmath. Anyway, your comments nicely sum up what there is to say on the subject.

Comment: @Georges: Don't think too much. Your comments are interesting and there will be no war.

Comment: @t.b. Since your comments seem to address all of OPs questions, could you please turn them into an answer?